# ElasticSearch Java API - Query Builder

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, query-builder

I'm currently working on elasticsearch where I've created a query :

```
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"match": {
          "companyId": 35
        }},
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "movie",
            "fields": ["name", "description"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

For which I have build QueryBuilder in JAVA :

```
        SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest("faqs");//index name
        SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
                
        QueryBuilder mulMatch = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(name,"name", "description").type("phrase").boost(5);
        QueryBuilder cId = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("companyId", companyId).boost(5);
        QueryBuilder must = QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(cId).must(mulMatch).boost(5);
        
        searchSourceBuilder.query(must);
        searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
        System.out.println("SS Query : " + searchSourceBuilder);

        return searchSourceBuilder;
```

which gives me query created as :

```
{"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"match":{"companyId":{"query":35,"operator":"OR","prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"lenient":false,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"boost":5.0}}},{"multi_match":{"query":"movie","fields":["description^1.0","name^1.0"],"type":"phrase","operator":"OR","slop":0,"prefix_length":0,"max_expansions":50,"zero_terms_query":"NONE","auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query":true,"fuzzy_transpositions":true,"boost":5.0}}],"adjust_pure_negative":true,"boost":5.0}}}
```

However, I require output such as :

```
{
          "Id": 1,
          "name": "Controle",
          "description": "Welcome movie",
          "visibility": "2",
          "isarticleEnabled": false,
          "companyId": 35,
          "categoryId": 0        
}
```

Though I'm getting output as(API Response) :

```
{
    "suggestOnly": false,
    "fragment": false
}
```

So to get such a response, what should I exactly do?
One solution I've got is of using Search Response such as :

```
SearchResponse res = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

But still, this is not actually working with ElasticsearchRestTemplate and RestHighLevelClient.

Note: I've searched for all the relative solutions, i.e. Search Request, Search Response,  but I was unable to get any of the proper solutions.

Comment: Maybe start by posting how exactly do you process your response? You can check that the builder builds the query you need by copy-pasting it to Kibana (CURL, Postman or whatever you are using).

Comment: Do you want to print response after executing query to Elasticsearch ? Can you put your actual output as well, same as expected output you have given.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe they should be merged instead of overriding.
`searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.boolQuery().filter(mulMatch).filter(cId).filter(must));`